# Laravel factory creation of Eloquent Models creates models with wrong attributes

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a seeder in which I try to bind `possibilities` to `questions` using `factory`.

```
...
  $question->possibilities()->saveMany(
    factory(Possibility::class, $random_num)
      ->make()
      ->each(function ($item, $index) use ($correct_answer) {
        if ($index === $correct_answer) {
          $item->correct = true;
        }
      })
    );
...
```

When I use factory the Eloquent model has an attribute of `answer` despite me removing the answer column from the migrations and removing all occurrences of `answer` in the `Possibility` model.

The Possibility Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Possibility extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['question_id', 'correct'];

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Question');
    }
}
```

The Possibility migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePossibilitiesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('possibilities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            // $table->string('answer');
            $table->boolean('correct')->default(false);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_id');
            $table
                ->foreign('question_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('questions')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('possibilities');
    }
}
```

When I use the `Model::create` without using factory I get don't have the attribute as expected.

```
$possibility = Possibility::create([
  'question_id' => $question->id,
  'correct' => 0
]);
```

**EDIT**

Missed something extremely obvious, the `PossibilityFactor` definition itself. Thanks to @lagbox for pointing it out.

Comment: probably because the factory you made for Possibilities is returning an array with the key 'answer' ... eloquent knows nothing about the your schema at all, you can assign any attributes you want to any model

Comment: I'm a bit confused what your problem is. Would you mind explaining in a bit more detail what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a factory for `Possibility`. In that you are defining the array of attributes to be used. You are returning an array with a key for `answer`. Remove that.

Answer (score -2):

This is probably what you need

```
factory(Possibility::class, $random_num)->create([
    'question_id' => $question->id,
])->each(function ($item, $index) use ($correct_answer) {
    if ($index === $correct_answer) {
       $item->correct = true;
    } else {
        $item->correct = false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? When you post an answer, please post an answer. To request clarification, leave a comment, something like "does setting `$item->correct = false;` in an `else` block change anything?".